# Browser sync scroll not working across browsers

Tags: vagrant, gulp, ubuntu-14.04, browser-sync

I have been trying to solve this issue with broswersync for couple of days. Any help in this will be highly appreciated.

**My Env:**

I am on windows and my server in Ubuntu in a vagrant box. I have port forwarding on, and use port 3000 to map to port 3000 on my vagrant.
So the URL I use from the host machine is http://localhost:3000/index.html, and if from outside, then http://MY_IP_ADDRESS:3000/index.html

**Description:**

I have CSS injection, reload, form sync, clicks, working across all browsers and devices. 
What does not work is the sync scroll and below are the scenarios.

1. scroll sync works only in chrome, in desktop mode ie, if I open the
   same URL in chrome in multiple windows in desktop mode, it works fine.
2. If i have mobile mode on, on chrome and desktop mode, the scroll sync does not work.
3. If I open the link on a firefox, safari, IE, the scroll sync does
   not work across them.
4. I cannot scroll across different devices and
   browsers by opening the link on multiple devices.

My Gulp:

I work from windows, but my server is on vagrant/ubuntu.
Here is my Gulp config for browser sync and watch.

```
// Static server
gulp.task('browser-sync', function () {
        browserSync({
                server: {
                        baseDir: "www"
                },
                ghostMode: {
                        scroll: true
                }
        });
});
// Static Server + watching scss/html files
gulp.task('serve', ['scss'], function () {

        browserSync({
                server: "./www"
        });
        gulp.watch(paths.scss, ['scss',browserSync.reload]);
        gulp.watch(paths.html, ['html',browserSync.reload]);
        gulp.watch(paths.js, ['js',browserSync.reload]);
        //gulp.watch("*.html").on('change', reload);
});
```

Thanks for your help in advance..

Comment: whats your BrowserSync version?

Comment: thanks for the response. It is 2.6.4

Comment: hmm strange, I tried here a simple webapp (just html and js) with browsersync 2.6.4 and could not sync the scroll too... just the clicks :(

Comment: thats bad... I have raised it on browsersync Github a few days back, but no response. 
https://github.com/BrowserSync/browser-sync/issues/579

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I recently ran into this problem as well. I found out that my problem was not having a html5 doctype.

Do you have an html5 doctype on your page? If not, try adding one.

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: Hi mate,
I did have it, but recently updated browser-sync again, and it all worked like magic... Not sure why it occurred.  But thanks a lot again mate for the reply.

Comment: I would add you 100 upvotes if I could. As a newbie that is starting with these kind of tools, things like that might seem obvious for some, when they really are not for people like me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled into this issue as well. When I access the URL at http://localhost:3000 in my machine and http://MY_LOCAL_IP:3000 from my device, the sync wont work. Not only scroll, but clicks and from actions as well. I've tried to change the settings from http://localhost:3001 (BS UI, a nice addition IMO) but it still won't work.

Here's my BS task:

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', ['default'], function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: './app'
    }
  });
});
```

Then I tried to access http://MY_LOCAL_IP:3000 both from my machine and my device, and it worked as expected. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: Hi @Aris, thanks a lot for the answer. I tried that, but works only for chrome on desktop. Does not work for chrome in mobile mode or multiple devices. The click, forms sync etc works except the scroll...

Comment: Really? I've tried from my 2 devices (Android/Chrome, WinPhone/IE) and it works as expected.

Edit: I don't use `ghostMode` in my BS config. After using `ghostMode` scroll won't work. Try to disable it

Comment: I tried removing ghostmode, with no result.. WHich version of browsersync are you using?

Comment: Hmm strange. I use 2.6.4 too, but I'm not using vagrant.

Answer (score 0):

I've just encountered this issue myself. [Drew's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30903854/6496664) about a missing HTML5 doctype causing the problem led me to look at my own doctype.

My doctype was there, but I had a class on the HTML tag. Removing this class restored scroll synchronisation for me. Adding the class back broke sync.

It's worth mentioning that this issue seems to occur only when a class is added to the HTML tag *manually*. Any classes added via DOM manipulation (using Modernizr for example) do not break scroll sync.

Running BrowserSync version 2.13.0 which is the latest version at this point in time.